# How do I pass a function pointer recursively?

Tags: iterator, rust

I want to write an `Iterator` adaptor which applies a function recursively to its underlying `Iterator`. Recursively because the variant  `IR::Loop` includes a `Vec<IR>`, of which an iterator should also be passed to the function.

The function should take an `&mut Iterator<Item = IR>` and use it to compute the next value of the iterator, (like [`itertools::batching`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.6.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.batching)).

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

#[derive(Clone)]
enum IR {
    OperationA,
    OperationB,
    Loop(Vec<IR>),
}

pub trait MyItertools: Iterator {
    fn apply_recursive<F: Fn(&mut Peekable<Self>) -> Option<Self::Item>>(
        self,
        f: F,
    ) -> ApplyRecursive<Self, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: Clone,
    {
        ApplyRecursive {
            iter: self.peekable(),
            f: f,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> MyItertools for T
where
    T: Iterator,
{
}

//applies a function recursively to some Iterator with Item=IR
#[derive(Clone)]
struct ApplyRecursive<I, F>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Clone,
{
    iter: Peekable<I>,
    f: F,
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item = IR>, F> Iterator for ApplyRecursive<I, F>
where
    F: Fn(&mut Peekable<I>)
       -> Option<I::Item>,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        match self.iter.peek() {
            Some(&IR::Loop(code)) => {
                self.iter.next(); //advance the iterator
                let code: Vec<IR> = code.into_iter().apply_recursive(self.f).collect();

                Some(IR::Loop(code))
            }
            Some(x) => (self.f)(&mut self.iter),
            None => None,
        }
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.iter.size_hint()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=485034f9e4f717cd5f9f018a54d729b6&version=stable)

What am I doing wrong? I don't even understand the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> F: std::ops::Fn<(&'r mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:54:54
   |
54 |                 let code: Vec<IR> = code.into_iter().apply_recursive(self.f).collect();
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>` is not implemented for `F`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where for<'r> F: std::ops::Fn<(&'r mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>` bound

error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> F: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:54:54
   |
54 |                 let code: Vec<IR> = code.into_iter().apply_recursive(self.f).collect();
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>` is not implemented for `F`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where for<'r> F: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>` bound

error: no method named `collect` found for type `ApplyRecursive<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>, F>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:54:78
   |
54 |                 let code: Vec<IR> = code.into_iter().apply_recursive(self.f).collect();
   |                                                                              ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `F : std::ops::Fn<(&mut std::iter::Peekable<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>>,)>`, `ApplyRecursive<std::vec::IntoIter<IR>, F> : std::iter::Iterator`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following trait defines an item `collect`, perhaps you need to implement it:
   = help: candidate #1: `std::iter::Iterator`
```

Comment: For readability-sake, I'd highly recommend not mixing the inline trait constraints `<A: Foo>` with the `where` clause. Once it's long or complicated, move wholesale to the `where` clause. My preference is to *always* use the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last error indicates that *you don't have an `Iterator`*. `Iterator` is only implemented for your struct under certain conditions, and you aren't meeting them. The second error explains why.

> the trait `for<'r> Fn<(&'r mut IntoIter<IR>,)>` is not implemented for the type `F`

So, why does the compiler think this won't work? Let's look at your constraints:

```
impl<I, F> Iterator for ApplyRecursive<I, F>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = IR>
    F: Fn(&mut Peekable<I>) -> Option<I::Item>,
```

This structure refers to a *concrete* type `I` that implements `Iterator`. Then `F` is a *concrete* type that accepts a mutable reference to the **same** concrete type as `I`. However, you try to use your function (specialized for whatever type it happens to be) on the concrete type `IntoIter` - but this might be a **different** concrete type!

The easiest fix is to remove the generics here:

```
impl<F> Iterator for ApplyRecursive<vec::IntoIter<IR>, F>
where
    F: Fn(&mut vec::IntoIter<IR>) -> Option<IR>,
{
    type Item = IR;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<IR> {
```

This unlocks a whole other slew of errors about mutability, accessing private fields, and exporting private types, but I think it gets over this hump.

Alternatively, we can change `F` to accept a *trait object*, and not worry about specializing it:

```
pub trait CustomIter: Iterator {
    fn apply_recursive<F>(self, f: F) -> ApplyRecursive<Self, F>
    where
        F: Fn(&mut Iterator<Item = Self::Item>) -> Option<Self::Item>,
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: Clone,
    {
        ApplyRecursive { iter: self.peekable(), f: f }
    }
}

impl<I, F> Iterator for ApplyRecursive<I, F>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = IR>,
    F: Fn(&mut Iterator<Item = IR>) -> Option<IR>,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<IR> {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you can explain this a lot better than the compiler haha ;) Generics are the hardest part of rust for me, but I've learned a lot today thanks to you!